# Retrofit 1.9.0 JSON doesn't fill every fields

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit

I am trying get JSON form http://httpbin.org/get. It look like

```
{
"args": {}, 
"headers": {
  "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*  /*;q=0.8", 
"Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate", 
"Accept-Language": "pl,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3", 
"Cookie": "_ga=GA1.2.1591535064.1485716088; _gat=1", 
"Host": "httpbin.org", 
"Referer": "http://httpbin.org/", 
"Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1", 
"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:51.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/51.0"
}, 
"origin": "83.10.45.163", 
"url": "http://httpbin.org/get"
}
```

I used http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ to convert JSON to POJO:

```
-----------------------------------com.app.apitest.test.Args.java-----------------------------------

package com.app.apitest.test;


public class Args {


}
-----------------------------------com.app.apitest.test.Example.java-----------------------------------

package com.app.apitest.test;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Example {

@SerializedName("args")
@Expose
private Args args;
@SerializedName("headers")
@Expose
private Headers headers;
@SerializedName("origin")
@Expose
private String origin;
@SerializedName("url")
@Expose
private String url;

public Args getArgs() {
return args;
}

public void setArgs(Args args) {
this.args = args;
}

public Headers getHeaders() {
return headers;
}

public void setHeaders(Headers headers) {
this.headers = headers;
}

public String getOrigin() {
return origin;
}

public void setOrigin(String origin) {
this.origin = origin;
}

public String getUrl() {
return url;
}

public void setUrl(String url) {
this.url = url;
}

}
-----------------------------------com.app.apitest.test.Headers.java-----------------------------------

package com.app.apitest.test;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Headers {

@SerializedName("Accept")
@Expose
private String accept;
@SerializedName("Accept-Encoding")
@Expose
private String acceptEncoding;
@SerializedName("Accept-Language")
@Expose
private String acceptLanguage;
@SerializedName("Cookie")
@Expose
private String cookie;
@SerializedName("Host")
@Expose
private String host;
@SerializedName("Referer")
@Expose
private String referer;
@SerializedName("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests")
@Expose
private String upgradeInsecureRequests;
@SerializedName("User-Agent")
@Expose
private String userAgent;

public String getAccept() {
return accept;
}

public void setAccept(String accept) {
this.accept = accept;
}

public String getAcceptEncoding() {
return acceptEncoding;
}

public void setAcceptEncoding(String acceptEncoding) {
this.acceptEncoding = acceptEncoding;
}

public String getAcceptLanguage() {
return acceptLanguage;
}

public void setAcceptLanguage(String acceptLanguage) {
this.acceptLanguage = acceptLanguage;
}

public String getCookie() {
return cookie;
}

public void setCookie(String cookie) {
this.cookie = cookie;
}

public String getHost() {
return host;
}

public void setHost(String host) {
this.host = host;
}

public String getReferer() {
return referer;
}

public void setReferer(String referer) {
this.referer = referer;
}

public String getUpgradeInsecureRequests() {
return upgradeInsecureRequests;
}

public void setUpgradeInsecureRequests(String upgradeInsecureRequests) {
this.upgradeInsecureRequests = upgradeInsecureRequests;
}

public String getUserAgent() {
return userAgent;
}

public void setUserAgent(String userAgent) {
this.userAgent = userAgent;
}

}
```

But when I got Result my  Example.class doesn't fill properly. There is some null fields...
Look at SS: [image: SS]

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It is because headers (and arg) is not truly set of fixed fields. It is `Map<String, String>`. And your android client not send that fields.

For example response with curl:[image: curl]

You can see true response which your client receive from server with [logging interceptor](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-log-requests-and-responses) or [stetho](http://facebook.github.io/stetho/)